# Nuance when using "も"

Tags: particle-も

I'm trying to figure out the nuance between:

> 学校まで1時間**も**掛かります。

and

> 学校まで1時間掛かります。

Book says it's used to express something plentiful, but I'm not sure what exactly that means. What is the fine difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used with quantities, も is used to add emphasis and/or emotion, whether in a positive or negative sense.

As such it can often be translated to mean “as much as”, “as many as” with a positive verb; or “as little as”, “as few as” with a negative verb.

For example, compare the following:

> １万円、もらった。
>
> I received 10,000 yen. (neutral statement of fact)
>
> １万円ももらった。
>
> I received (as much as) 10,000 yen. (10,000 yen is a lot!)

Equally...

> １万円かかった。
>
> It cost 10,000 yen. (neutral statement of fact)
>
> １万円もかかった。
>
> It cost (as much as) 10,000 yen. (expensive!!)

Note that both sentences were positive verb sentences, but the emotional emphasis was positive when receiving and negative when paying. The emphasis/emotion conveyed depends thus on the context.

In your sentence, therefore:

> 学校まで１時間かかります。
>
> It takes an hour to (get to) school. (neutral statement of fact)
>
> 学校まで1時間もかかります。
>
> It takes (as much as) an hour to (get to) school. (Likely expressing frustration that an hour is a long time to commute each way!)

Does that clarify it for you? I would recommend [Maggie Sensei’s post](http://maggiesensei.com/2013/10/08/japanese-particle-%E3%82%82mo-to-emphasize-the-number-%E3%80%8C%E4%B8%80%E2%98%85%E3%82%82%E3%80%8D/) on this topic, from where those examples were drawn, if you want to look at a more in-depth explanation. Hope that helps!