# Understanding ある as a 連体形

Tags: translation, 連体形

The sentence

> 人間の背丈ほどもある雑草の中を探検すると蛇に出くわした。

translates to

> I ran into a snake when I was exploring through weeds as tall as a person.

**Question:** What is ある connected to? Is it a 連体形 modifying 雑草, as in

> ある雑草

If so, what purpose is it serving? It sounds like it's just saying "existing-weeds", which is pretty much the same thing as "weeds", no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that ある is in the 連体形, and 人間の背丈ほどもある is a relative clause that modifies 雑草. The "original" sentence is:

> (その)雑草**は**(高さ**が**)人間の背丈ほどもある。
>
> The weeds are as tall as a human.
> (literally: As for the weeds, the height is as much as a human's height.)

This ある may still seem tricky, but we use ある this way to express the weight or the size of something. You may temporarily forget the meaning of "to exist".

- この蛇は(長さが)3メートル(も)ある。
  This snake is 3 meters long.
- 彼は(体重が)80kg以上(も)ある。
  He weights more than 80 kg.

(も [indicates the number is large](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69513/5010). The が-marked subject like 体重 is typically omitted.)

And we can make relativized phrases like so:

- (長さが)3メートルある蛇
  a snake that is 3 meters long
- (体重が)80kg以上ある男
  a man who weighs more than 80 kg

Here's a relevant dictionary definition:

> #### ある
>
> ❼《数値を伴って》あるものがそのような物理的な属性をもっている。そのような数量が認められる。「彼は体重が一〇〇キロもある」「塔の高さは五〇メートルある」
> <sub>(Source: 大修館書店 明鏡国語辞典 第三版)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for another great answer. Related question: is "雑草の中を探検する" considered a relative clause in this sentence, and is that why する is in the non-past tense, while 出くわした is in the past tense? (For that matter, ある is also in the non-past tense, for I assume the same reason).

Comment: @naruto Out of curiosity, would the meaning be the same if もある were replaced by でもある? Or is this ungrammatical. For example: この蛇は長さが3メートルでもある.

Comment: @George No, と is not a noun in the first place, so 探検する cannot form a relative clause. The verb before と [must be non-past](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1784/5010).

Comment: @jogloran もある and でもある are different. でもある is である (is) + も (also), so your sentence means "Besides/Also, this snake's length is 3 meters."